# How to access atribute of instance I want to validate from inside serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my view I do following:

```
class ReviewViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    #queryset, serializer_class and permission_classes defined here

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        title_id = self.kwargs.get('title_id')
        title = get_object_or_404(Title, pk=title_id)
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, title=title)
```

I want to validate that review doesn't exist yet. I'm trying to do this in serializer's `validate()`:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='pk', read_only='True')
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', read_only='True')

    def validate(self, data):
        title = # <-- How to get title here?
        author = self.context['request'].user
        queryset = Review.objects.all().filter(title=title, author=author)
        if queryset.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Review alredy exists')
        return(data)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Review
```

Attempt to do `title = self.title` raises `AttributeError: 'ReviewSerializer' object has no attribute 'title'`

How to access `title` from inside `validate()` in my case?

Here's my `Review` model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        unique_together = ['title', 'author']

    title = models.ForeignKey(
        Title,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reviews',
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reviews',
    )
    text = models.TextField('Review text')
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        'Review score',
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(10)
        ]
    )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Date and time of review',
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True
    )
```

Comment: `title` is a ***read_only*** field, which means the corresponding field won't take any input to validate

Answer (score -1):

The response to your question lies in the documentation : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation

About the `validate` method:

> This method takes a single argument, which is a dictionary of field values

If you look at the code sample in the doc, you'll see that all data that you might need to validate are in the `data` argument of the `validate` method.

Hence, the title is in `data['title']`.

Comment: `data` object is an `OrderedDict([('text', 'qwerty'), ('score', 5)])` and have no key `title`

Comment: An ordered dict is nothing else than a dict with some methods for ordering. If the `title` key is not inside, it means that it hasn't been properly submitted. As you can see, your dict contains a `text` and a score `key` corresponding to the fields in your `Review` model. Try to see why the `title` data has not been submitted along with `text` and `key`.